Parve food at school
If my school serves rice as a side dish to chicken, I am unsure whether or not they use the same silverware to serve us. Do I have to wait a full six hours after eating the rice or can I eat the rice And eat dairy after

Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Your question was closed because this site is not a good place for personal questions or those that need knowledge of specific situations. Those should be asked to a rabbi well-versed in the relevant laws who will ask questions on context and personal specifics to come to a good answer. This site can't substitute for this. Please don't let this deter you from coming back to learn with us.

Could rephrase in broader terms -- "if rice is served as a side with chicken, does eating the rice require one to wait six hours?" That question would be answered here.

@Shalom the difficulty of course is that it depends if the rice was cooked with meat broth or not - and we won't know that - so in the end the OP will always be required to ask the mashgiach
